# When trying to upload file, FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed() is thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to upload images by using the `IFormFile`. But I got an error at this line:

```
using (var stream = _file.OpenReadStream())
```

The error (stacktrace as the bottom):

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
> 'FileBufferingReadStream'.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed()

I've already searched for a solution but none of them worked for me.

Here is the full code of the method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Product product)
{
    var newFileName = string.Empty;
    var fileName = string.Empty;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        IFormFile _file = UploadFiles.File;
        ResizeOptions resize;
        var myUniqueFileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
        var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(_file.FileName);
        newFileName = myUniqueFileName + FileExtension;
        fileName = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "ProductImages") + $@"\{newFileName}";

        using (var stream = _file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            using (var output = new MemoryStream())
            using (Image image = Image.Load(stream))
            {
                image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(image.Width / 3, image.Height));
                image.Save(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, @"ProductImages\Thumbnails") + $@"\{newFileName}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The StackTrace:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.set_Position(long value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile.OpenReadStream()
netcore.Controllers.Invent.ProductController+<Create>d__7.MoveNext() in ProductController.cs
+
                using (var stream = _file.OpenReadStream())
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace (with line number). Also, the output variable is not used.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-and-display-image-in-asp-net-core-3-1/

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-download-files-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: @Kalten I added the stracktrace. for the output variable I deleted it but I have the error again

Comment: Can you please share with us the implementation of the UploadedFiles class? It does not seems a built-in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another solution and it works. I don't know why :D