# Could not find file Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream

Tags: f#, azure-functions, type-providers, f#-data

I'm running an Azure Function locally in Visual Studio but receive the error "Could not find file 'C:\Users\kbiondi\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.13.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream'. (details below).

The code that triggers this error seems to be:
`let! parameters = JsonTypeProvider.AsyncLoad(req.Body.ToString())`

Using `let parameters = JsonTypeProvider.Load(req.Body)` the function runs without problem.

I have reloaded various nuget packages and the sdk, but this problem persists.

> Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       4.0.4483 Commit
> hash: N/A  (64-bit) Function Runtime Version: 4.1.3.17473
>
> [2022-05-19T18:24:10.578Z] Csproj not found in
> C:\Users\kbiondi\OneDrive -
> CalPERS\Repos\AzFunction_BpipeRefData\bin\Debug\net6.0 directory tree.
> Skipping user secrets file configuration.
>
> Functions:
>
> ```
>     BpipeReferenceDataRequest: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/BpipeReferenceDataRequest
> ```
>
> For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
> [2022-05-19T18:24:16.773Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID
> '0000000000000000000000001F77FD18'. [2022-05-19T18:24:43.597Z]
> Executing 'BpipeReferenceDataRequest' (Reason='This function was
> programmatically called via the host APIs.',
> Id=13a1beaf-3141-4112-a086) The Azure Function Received a
> Request... Request failed with the following error:
>
> Message: Could not find file
> 'C:\Users\kbiondi\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.13.0\cli_x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream'.
>
> Source: System.Private.CoreLib
>
> TargetSite: Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle
> CreateFile(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess,
> System.IO.FileShare, System.IO.FileOptions)
>
> StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath,
> FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions
> options)    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String
> fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share,
> FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)    at
> System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode
> mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64
> preallocationSize)    at
> FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncRead@219-9.Invoke(Unit unitVar)    at
> Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.CallThenInvoke[T,TResult](AsyncActivation`1 ctxt, TResult result1, FSharpFunc`2 part2) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 447    at
> BpipeProcess.BpipeReferenceDataRequest.Pipe #1 input at line
> 16@21-11.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)    at BpipeProcess.BpipeReferenceDataRequest.Pipe #1 input at line 16@20-14.Invoke(AsyncActivation`1 ctxt)    at
> Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.Execute(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
> in D:\a_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line
> 104[2022-05-19T18:24:43.679Z] Executed 'BpipeReferenceDataRequest'
> (Succeeded, Id=13a1beaf-3141-4112-a086, Duration=101ms)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-fsharp)

> ***F# script (.fsx) is only supported by version 1.x of the Azure
> Functions runtime. If you want to use F# with version 2.x and later
> versions of the runtime, you must use a precompiled F# class library
> project (.fs). You create, manage, and publish an F# class library
> project using Visual Studio .***

You can use  in that line if wants http request e.g:- `let Run(req: HttpRequestMessage, log: ILogger) =`

*And make sure that your folder structure looks like below format:*

```
FunctionsProject
 | - MyFirstFunction
 | | - run.fsx
 | | - function.json
 | | - function.proj
 | - MySecondFunction
 | | - run.fsx
 | | - function.json
 | | - function.proj
 | - host.json
 | - extensions.csproj
 | - bin
```

For more information please refer the *aforementioned* and below links:

- [***SIMILAR ISSUE|SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614081/when-trying-to-upload-file-filebufferingreadstream-throwifdisposed-is-thrown)
- [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENT|Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities Namespace***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [***BLOG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities FileBufferingReadStream Examples***](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/FileBufferingReadStream/-/php-filebufferingreadstream-class-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This Azure function is currently running in-process. In the near future we will convert it to an isolated process function. At that time I will readdress this issue.